# ng-if not updated directly

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ng-if

What I'm trying to do in my controller is that:
        1. set variable vm.spinner = false;
2. send http request and after finish the request set vm.spinner = true;
i put that in my view:

```
 <div ng-if='vm.spinner' class=spinner></spinner>
```

I tried to print vm.spinner in side the div it puts true, but if I printed it out of it it prints false as soon as the http request finished. It seems that I have two vm.spinner one in my controller and another inside the ng-if scope !
this is my html view:

```
<div ng-if="!vm.spinner && !vm.gridOptions.data.length" class="empty-exams" >
    <img ng-src="assets/images/school/empty-fees.png"  />
    <div class="nothing-to-preview" translate="NothingToPreview"></div>
    <button class="start-exams-now" type="button"  name="button" ng-    click="vm.newFeeModal()">[['Start' | translate]] [['Now' | translate]]</button>
</div>
<div ng-if='vm.gridOptions.data.length' class="subjects-container">
  <div class="subjects-grid">
    <div class="above-grid-header">
      <span translate="Fees Configuration"></span>
      <span class="pointer-cursor" ng-click="vm.newFeeModal()">+ [[ 'New   Fee' | translate]]</span>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-itself" dir="[[lang=='en'?'ltr':'rtl']]" ui- grid="vm.gridOptions" ui-grid-edit ui-grid-pagination></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div ng-if='vm.spinner' class="spinner"></div>
```

and I tried to watch the vm.spinned .. it has changed as soon as the request done!
controller code

```
    FeesConfigController.$inject = ['ApiService', '$scope', 'ShareAnyData', 'FeesService', '$filter', '$uibModal', 'componentsPaths', 'logger'];
  function FeesConfigController(ApiService, $scope, ShareAnyData, FeesService, $filter, $uibModal, componentsPaths, logger){
    var instId = $scope.user.institute.id;
    var vm = this;
    ApiService.sendMultipleRequests({
        call: [FeesService.getFeeTypes, FeesService.getLeaderFeeTypes],
        params: [[instId], []],
        controller : FeesConfigControllerResolved,
        vm: this,
        controllerParams: [$scope, FeesService, $filter, logger, ShareAnyData, componentsPaths, $uibModal],
      })
  }
```

Note I update the vm.spinner in the ApiService.sendMultipleRequest
and I want to say that

```
 <div ng-if="!vm.spinner && !vm.gridOptions.data.length" class="empty-exams" >
```

This div will be show as soon as the request done and the spinner is false

### but the real spinner not disapear

I got an idea but I'm not sure about it. spinner class in my css is animated! so that I think my browser doesn't hide the spinner till the animation is done! I'm not gonna to test this right now till to speak with my other partner to update the spinner class in the css.

Comment: Can you provide the controller code?

Comment: ok i want to edit my post

Comment: I guess one question is why are you binding your view in your service?  This should be kept in the controller.

Comment: Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/93qzds0v/

Comment: this is like a fake controller .. and i made this because performance issues .. i translated every thing in the resolves to the controllers then i passed the real controller to the service to execute after the http requests done

Comment: so this to load the view before the resolves are done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use ng-class

```
<div ng-if="vm.spinner">
    <div ng-class="{'spinner': vm.spinner}"></div>
</div>
```

This way, the animation is never waited for.
I intentionally made a parent and a child divs, because spinners usually are inside some parent container.

PS: I just want to point out that the codes you put here, should be so simple and clear, with only the parameters needed for the issue.